# Rate of increase of water level in a wedge-shaped pool

Tags: calculus

Came across this problem in Serge Lang *A first course in calculus*, fifth edition. "A swimming pool is $25 ft$ wide, $40 ft$ long, $3 ft$ deep at one end and $9 ft$ deep at the other, the bottom being an inclined plane. If water is pumped into the pool at the rate of $10 cu.\ ft/min$, how fast is the water level rising when it is $4 ft$ deep at the deep end?"

I calculated $\frac{3}{100}$ $ft/min$, but Lang's appendix says $\frac{3}{200}$ $ft/min$. What is the right answer? The more explicit the argument the better. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share your logic used to calculate your solution?

Comment: Seems like a standard related rates problem. I’ll do this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle the inclined plane makes with the vertical. $\tan\theta = \frac{40}{6}$

The cross section of the water is a triangle.

At a depth $h$ at deep end, volume is given by

$V = \frac{1}{2} h\tan\theta * h * 25 = \frac{1}{2} 25 h^2\tan\theta \implies \frac{dV}{dt} = 25h \tan\theta \frac{dh}{dt} \implies \frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{3}{200}$